# Convert string to enum in a function

Tags: c#, string, enums

I have a method which takes in two enums and returns a `bool[]`. However, in practice I have a string that I want to pass it, by converting it to an enum.

I have the following code:

```
    path = StatePath.statePath(Enum.GetName(typeof(StatePath.States), currentState), (Enum.GetName(typeof(StatePath.States), stable_state_ENDDR));
```

Here, currentState and `stable_state_ENDDR` are strings that I retrieve from some other code. The values of those strings match enums in the States enum. The code throws an error, saying that I can't convert from string to enum. I have tried several of the examples I found on StackOverflow and Google alike, but none of the solutions worked. 
What to do?

Comment: Enum.Parse. Enum.GetName returns string, not enum. Provide signature of StatePath.statePath would be more clear. "Throws an error" in compile time or run time? Post the error.

Comment: `(StatePath.States) Enum.Parse(typeof(StatePath.States), currentState)` should give you the enum value. Your statePath method is probably accepting enums but you are passing in strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the signature of the function, this is quite difficult to answer, but I think you are looking for [Enum.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8): Declare the enums `eCurrentState` and `eStable_state_ENDDR`, then use

```
Enum.TryParse(currentState, out eCurrentState);

Enum.TryParse(stable_state_ENDDR, out eStable_state_ENDDR);

path = StatePath.statePath(eCurrentState, eStable_state_ENDDR);
```

If the `TryParse` fails, it returns `false`.

That being said, a general rule of thumb is to avoid scenarios like these and pass enums as `int` or `bit flags`, this is because internally thats how enums are stored, and require no conversion function to slow you down. Basically, `SomeEnum == someIntValue` would work directly without any conversion. So assuming you are getting your data from some server/db, simply request the data as a **numeric value equal to the index of the enum that it is declared in**. Conversely, store the data in the same way.

e.g. with any enum, with no attributes declared

```
enum SomeEnum
{
    abc, // 0
    def, // 1
    g    // 2
}
```

`abc == 0`, `def == 1`, `g == 2`, would return true.

Answer (score 1):

Call `Enum.Parse` and cast the return value to your enum type, e.g.:

```
string currentState = "...";
States states = (StatePath.States)Enum.Parse(typeof(StatePath.States), currentState);
```

There is a `TryParse` overload as well:

```
if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(StatePath.States), currentState, out object o))
    StatePath.States states = (StatePath.States)o;
```

...and a generic version that saves you from having to cast the value explicitly yourself:

```
if (Enum.TryParse(currentState, out StatePath.States state))
```

Comment: `TryParse` is a generic method. It doesn't take a `Type` as it's argument but rather as it's *type parameter*. In full form: `Enum.TryParse<StatePath.States>(currentState, out StatePath.States value)`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: It comes in a non-generic version as well. That's the one I have used in my example. But I have not updated my answer to reflect that there is a generic version that performs the casting for you.

Comment: I checked the reference source and MSDN prior to posting that. Weird.. its not in either place, but sure enough SharpLab shows it. Best I found was a request on github from several years ago to add it. Any idea when it was added?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: It's there, I promise :) Anyway, again, I updated my answer to also include the generic overload.

Comment: I'm no longer denying it exists as I can see it on SharpLab. It's also available in the [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c9d69e38d0e54bea5d188593ef6c3b30139f3ab1/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Enum.cs#L286) referencesource but *not* on referencesource.microsoft.com. It appears to be dotnet core (only?), added in netcoreapp1.1. Definitely confusing that it's not listed on MSDN (or I'm just blind)